# How to tag a credential in hyperledger indy wallet

Tags: tags, hyperledger, indy, hyperledger-indy

For indy wallet how can we attach tag on credential to achieve following in the use cases

1. To sort credentials based on date with issue date tag added to the credential
2. To fetch credentials based on subject with subject as tag.

https://hyperledger-indy.readthedocs.io/projects/hipe/en/latest/text/0013-wallets/README.html#sample-wql-query-1

The add_record_tags function given here is not available for indy wallet because no indy prefix is attached to function and currently proverStoreCredential does not allow to add custom tags https://www.npmjs.com/package/indy-sdk#non_secrets